# ubuntu 16 battery indicator has disappeared

Tags: 16.04, unity, battery

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS running alongside with windows 8 (dual boot), everything was fine till suddenly the battery level indicator on the bar menu of (unity desktop) has gone. Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge indicator-power
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

Comment: Done, but it has updated the system settings menu including the power options, but the battery indicator doesn't shown up yet.