# Ubuntu 16.04, Battery not showing

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery

I recently converted my Surface book 2 to ubuntu 16.04 using a USB. However, for whatever reason, the battery indicator is missing

[image]

I have tried some of the other solutions on this site, but none of them have worked for me. Here's a few other screenshots that might help (I have my power adapter connected during these screenshots):

(Settings > Power)
[image]

[image]

EDIT: From one of the answers below, please see my terminal output. It says the command doesn't exist, but also that `indicator-power` is installed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I ran into this on another question where I tried, unsuccessfully, to help. The problem seems to be "Windows Surface" and kernel (and possibly secure boot) - both a bit out of my lane. There is apparently another kernel that needs to be installed and they are also version dependent. If someone a bit better than me could use the following links to assist both of these folks, I'm sure it would be appreciated. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295073/i-am-having-problems-with-displaying-battery-percentage/1295075#comment2200159_1295075 ...there are additional links on that question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure the power indicator is installed first:

```
indicator-power
```

And if it isn't, then I'd install it:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

If it is installed, then it might have just crashed. I'd try restarting it:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service &disown
```

And if that's still not working, then I'd reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-power
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. Could you check my edited question?

Comment: What do you see when you run "gsettings list-recursively | grep settings-daemon.plugins.power"? 

You should see a line that says "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true" but I'm wondering if you're going to see "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false"

Comment: Ran that, and I see the active true line,.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I’ve seen work with a couple of different Surface models is to use Gnome Tweaks:

1. `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
2. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so.6.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so.4`
3. `sudo systemctl restart upower`

From here, you can open the gnome-tweaks application, choose "top bar", then toggle battery percentage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting this error "ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so.4': File exists", could you help (thanks for the answer!)

Comment: Could you confirm the existence of the `libusbmuxd` file with this: `ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd*`. You should see the file above, and possibly a symbolic link as well.

Comment: yes, i see both of them

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer, with included comments.

1. Try installing `gnome-tweaks`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
   gnome-tweaks &
   ```

   and activating the *Battery percentage*.
   You reported an error, but it is not clear at which point you got it.

[image]

2. Try options [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/482152/226614). It is a post from askubuntu.com, so a copy is not needed.
3. Check (and report) the output of

   ```
    gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage
   ```

   If `false` try setting it to `true` with

   ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true
   ```
4. Check (and report) the output of

   ```
    sudo service upower status
   ```

   If not active try enabling it with

   ```
    sudo service upower start
   ```
5. Try installing [battery-status](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu)

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status && sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install battery-status
    /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator
   ```
6. Try a newer Ubuntu. (I know this is not a solution just to fix the battery indicator, but you may get a lot of extra benefits).
   Related:

   5.1. [Can I run Ubuntu on a Surface laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112379/can-i-run-ubuntu-on-a-surface-laptop)

   5.2. https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/b9t1jd/full_guide_on_getting_ubuntu_1804_working_on/

   5.3. https://www.most-useful.com/ubuntu-20-04-linux-on-surface-pro-4-working-pretty-well.html
7. With [`battery-monitor`](https://github.com/maateen/battery-monitor) YMMV. See https://www.2daygeek.com/monitor-laptop-battery-charging-state-linux/ also

---

**Note**
that `indicator-power` seems buggy

1. [Indicator-Power-Message: exiting: service couldn't acquire or lost ownership of busname](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633992/indicator-power-message-exiting-service-couldnt-acquire-or-lost-ownership-of)
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1257251?comments=all

---

**Related**

1. [No battery status icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68445/no-battery-status-icon)
2. [ubuntu 16 battery indicator has disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895777/ubuntu-16-battery-indicator-has-disappeared)

Answer (score 0):

i had problem with ubuntu 20.04.02

```
$ sudo systemctl restart upower
```

> Job for upower.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to
> the control process. See "systemctl status upower.service" and
> "journalctl -xe" for details.

checking with

```
 $ systemctl --failed
```

UNIT              LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● upower.service    loaded failed failed Daemon for power management

so i had to install

```
$ sudo apt install systemd:amd64 systemd-timesyncd:amd64
```

and now service started and battery indicator is back

```
$ sudo systemctl start upower
```